# Json Deserialization in an ASP.NET not working properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have an API that returns the following response as string

```
[
 {
    "id": "62a9f8f90346133662624bd3",
    "referenceID": "test1",
    "additionalInfoList": ["string"]
 },
 {
    "id": "62a9fba50346133662624bd4",
    "referenceID": "111",
    "additionalInfoList": ["string"]
 }
]
```

edit: where the exact formatting of the string is as follows with escaping backslashes:

```
"[{\"id\":\"62a9f8f90346133662624bd3\",\"referenceID\":\"test1\",\"additionalInfoList\":[\"string\"]},{\"id\":\"62a9fba50346133662624bd4\",\"referenceID\":\"111\",\"additionalInfoList\":[\"string\"]}]"
```

and the following class model

```
public class IncidentModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string referenceID { get; set; }
    public List<string> AdditionalInfoList { get; set; }
}
```

The problem arises in the code to deserialize. While I get a list with 2 elements, there is no data, only some generic metadata and fields that are not part of the model.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetIncidentsAsync()
    {
        List<IncidentModel> incidents = new List<IncidentModel>();
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Incident/GetAllIncidents.json/"))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
                incidents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IncidentModel>>(apiResponse);
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult(incidents);
    }
```

The attached image shows the data inside incidents.
How can I solve this?[image]

Comment: Can you please update and show contents of the apiResponse string?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the JSON string and c# model shown, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/td1B9X.  Can you share a [mcve]?  What is `HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode` in the case where the `apiResponse` cannot be deserialized?

Comment: {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2022 19:22:38 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Via: 1.1 vegur
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}} @dbc

Comment: I can not see any problem. What is the error?

Comment: the problem is that the incident list doesn't contain the data from the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out in Pages, I had a page named Incident. Because I use Razor pages, this page had a Model, named **IncidentModel.cshtml.cs** which was overriding the **IncidentModel.cs** from the **Models** folder. Renaming the model fixed the problem.